# construct a set $H$ such that $S\cup H$ is open and $\lambda(H) < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let S be a lebesgue measurable subset of R and let lambda denote the lebesgue measure. Show that there exists sets $H$ and $K$ such that

1) $S \cup H$ is open and $\lambda(H) < \epsilon$.

2) $S \backslash K$ is clsoed and $\lambda(K) < \epsilon$

for 1): I have set $H = \cup_i^\infty(a_i,b_i) \backslash S$ and we have for any set $S$ $\lambda(\cup_i^\infty(a_i,b_i)) < \lambda(S) + \epsilon$. This was enough to get the result only for $\lambda(S) < \infty$. I am not sure what to do if $\lambda(S) = \infty$ or for 2)

Comment: Can you use the statement, that every set, having a finite Lebesgue measure is a subset of a $G_\delta$ set of the same Lebesgue measure?

Comment: For 2) you can similarly use inner regularity. There exists a closed $C$ such that $C \subset S$ and $m(S \setminus C) < \epsilon$. Then take $K := S \setminus C$.

Comment: @ÉdesIstvánGergely I've never used this statement before, so I am going to go with no. Epsilon - thanks that sorts out part 2) - I am still trying to figure out the end of 1)

Comment: I think this implies from Caratheodory theorem. There is some work though